# Lie algebra Representation of the group $(\mathbb{R},+)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, representation-theory

I am reading Peter Woit's book Quantum Theory, Groups and Representations, section 10.1 (a similar version can be found [here](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/QM/qmbook.pdf)). I am reading the part where he introduces the representation of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R}).$ He said the following:

> The simplest case is the representation induced on functions on $\mathbb{R}$ by the action of $\mathbb{R}$ on itself by translation. Here, $a\in \mathbb{R}$ acts on $q\in \mathbb{R}$ (where $q$ is a coordinate on $\mathbb{R}$) by
> $$q\to a\cdot q=q+a,$$
> which induces a representation $\pi:\mathbb{R}\to GL(L^2(\mathbb{R}))$ given by
> $$\pi(g)f(q)=f(g^{-1}\cdot q)$$
> for which this case will be
> $$\pi(a)f(q)=f(q-a).$$
> To get the Lie algebra version of this representation, the above can be differentiated, finding
> $$\pi'(a)=-a\frac{d}{dq}.$$

**My Question: I don't see how to go from $\pi(a)f(q)=f(q-a)$ to $\pi'(a)=-a\frac{d}{dq}.$ I would appreciate if someone can explain it to me.** Here is what I have done so far:

By definition, the derivative $\pi'$ of the induced Lie algebra representation is related to the Lie group representation via
$$\pi'(X)=\frac{d}{dt}\pi(e^{tX})|_{t=0}.$$

Therefore, we have that

$$
\pi'(a)f(q)=\frac{d}{dt}\pi(e^{ta})f(q)|_{t=0}=\frac{d}{dt}f((-e^{ta})\cdot q)|_{t=0}=\frac{d}{dt}f(q-e^{ta})|_{t=0}=[f'(q-e^{ta})(-ae^{ta})]_{t=0}=-af'(q-1).
$$

So I didn't get the expected answer. Instead, I get a shift of the derivative $f'(q-1)$, but it should have been $f'(q)$.

Another method I try to use is by defining
$$\pi'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\pi(a+h)-\pi(a)}{h}.$$
But in the end I get $\pi'(a)f(q)=-f'(q-a).$ Another different answer, which is very weird. So I must have made some silly mistakes in my work.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Oops sorry, I thought since this is essentially how Peter Woit gets the momentum operator from a unitary representation of the group $\mathbb{R}$, this should be asked as a physics question. I can delete this post if needed.

Answer (score 6):

You must be careful - remember that the Lie algebra is given by the tangent space to the Lie group **at the identity element**.  The identity element of $G=(\mathbb R,+)$ is not $1\in \mathbb R$ but rather $0\in \mathbb R$. There are two ways to study this somewhat odd case clearly. We may either implement $G$ as a matrix group, or we may treat it as a smooth manifold.

The former is simpler.  Define
$$G := \left\{\pmatrix{1&a\\0&1}\in \mathbb R_{2\times 2}\ \bigg | \ a\in \mathbb R\right\}\simeq (\mathbb R,+)$$
In this form, the group operation is given by matrix multiplication, since
$$ \pmatrix{1&a\\0&1} \pmatrix{1&b\\0&1} = \pmatrix{1&a+b\\0&1}$$
Letting $a$ be infinitesimal, we find that the Lie algebra takes the form
$$\mathfrak g := \left\{\pmatrix{0&a\\0&0}\ \bigg| \ a\in \mathbb R\right\} \simeq (\mathbb R,+)$$
The exponential map is then straightforwardly given by
$$\exp\left(\pmatrix{0&a\\0&0}\right)= \pmatrix{1&a\\0&1}$$
Observe that both $G$ and $\mathfrak g$ are isomorphic to $(\mathbb R,+)$ - the former as a group, and the latter as a vector space - and that $G\ni \pmatrix{1&a\\0&1}$ and $\mathfrak g\ni \pmatrix{0&a\\0&0}$ may be identified with $a\in \mathbb R$.  This suggests - somewhat counterintuitively - that we might write $\exp(a) = a$, where the exponential map is (clearly) not the familiar exponential from elementary analysis.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you! Since you mentioned treating $\mathbb{R}$ as a smooth manifold, can we also argue as follows? The map $\text{exp}$ takes a vector $a\in T_0 \mathbb{R}$ to $\gamma_a(1)$, where $\gamma_a(t)$ is the unique geodesic $\gamma_a(t)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with $\gamma_a(0)=0,\gamma_a'(0)=a$, which is just the constant curve with initial velocity $a$. Therefore $\text{exp}(a)=a$?

Comment: @TianyiWang Yes, that's precisely the other option. Though one should be careful to say that it's not a geodesic (a curve of extremal length) but rather an integral curve of the left-invariant vector field whose element at $T_0\mathbb R$ is $a$.  This is of course just a constant vector field. And indeed, if we equip $\mathbb R$ with the metric $\langle a,b\rangle = ab$ then this curve will be a geodesic as well, but it's important I think to keep the concepts distinct.

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$\pi(a) f(q)=f(q- a) \approx f(q) - f'(q) a$

$\pi(a) = e^{-a \frac{\partial}{\partial q}} \approx 1- a\frac{\partial}{\partial q}$

$\pi'(a) |_{a=0} = - \frac{\partial}{\partial q} e^{-a \frac{\partial}{\partial q}}|_{a=0}\approx -\frac{\partial}{\partial q}$

*Physics From Symmetry*. Jakob Schwictenberg. Page 40.

*Physics From Finance*. Jakob Schwictenberg. Page 160.